# Find out which program is using all the disk when my screen saver is on

Tags: windows-8.1, task-manager, disk-activity

Right after my computer wakes up when I press a key, the disk usage drops from 100% to 5%. How do I find out which program is using the disk?

[image: task manager]

Windows 8.1, and I have a black screen saver, it's not running anything or any animations for the screen saver.

Comment: Try using the Resource Monitor. It should give you an Average CPU  value that you can sort by.

Comment: Run this http://pastebin.com/AyxAVU60 and stop the trace after you had the disk activity during idle, zip and upload the trace.

Comment: have you made a trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possibly  `Automatic Maintenance` which runs when your computer is idle.
Verify it from `Action Center` which shows its 'Last run time'.

Comment: It was Automatic Maintenance. I saw the last run time was 2m before the drop in disk activity before I got on the computer!

Answer (score 0):

It is probably Windows itself. Thing like defragmentation (or TRIM for SSDs), Windows Defender Scans, Windows Update Downloads and Search Indexing have been moved to the background to lessen the impact on the usability. Windows tries to do them only when idle, and (if it's a laptop) preferably when the laptop is plugged in.

Especially the indexing reads much data from the disk.